# Multiple http requests that has different URLs and data

Tags: concurrency, jmeter

I have a scenario to check out where my web application can sustain how many concurrent user registrations. Every user registration URLs and their data are unique. How can I simulate this using JMeter? I have the registration URLs with me.

Answer (score 0):

There are [different ways of parameterizing your JMeter test using external data](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-parameterization-the-complete-guide/) and the easiest / most commonly used one is storing your test data like URL into a [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file and using [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) to "feed" JMeter with the data from the CSV file.

Assuming you have `test.csv` file in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation which looks like:

```
URL
http://example.com/register/user1
http://example.com/register/user2
http://example.com/register/user3
etc.
```

1. Add CSV Data Set Config to your Test Plan and put `test.csv` file into "Filename" field

   [image]
2. In the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler put `${URL}` [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) reference into "Path" field. You can also change `HTTP Request` sampler name to be something like `Register: User - ${__threadNum}, URL: ${URL}` in order to be able to distinguish requests for different users

   [image]
3. Set "Number of Threads" to whatever value you need in the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)

   [image]
4. Add [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener to your Test Plan and run your test - you will see that each virtual user is picking next line from the CSV file:

   [image]

Comment: ok. Thanks for the reply. How do I simulate a condition where I submit these forms?

Comment: I want to submit each of these registrations not just accessing them and getting a response.